# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cattr)

Tags: docker

while installing cattr using docker hub image,(https://hub.docker.com/r/amazingcat/cattr)
got web interface to login, but getting error while creating admin user,

Error

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cattr)

web interface must be working

Comment: Your app failed to connect to the unix socket of the mysql database